# SQL Developer not showing tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I'm kinda new to SQL Developer, but I always heard a lot about it and how it was good. The thing is, my SQL Developer never showed my tables, nor had a "Tables" tab. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but, I've searched everywhere and, wherever I search they simply show that SQL Developer automatically generate the "Tables" tab when you connect. This never happened to me.

One more question, all of a sudden, my SQL Developer toolbars changed and the old ones simply vanished. And, when I say "all of a sudden" I mean it. I closed it and, when I opened, it changed. Also, the buttons doesn't work, none of them.

[image: Screenshot of SQL Developer]

Comment: Have you created a connection then tested it to make sure it works?

Comment: Yes, I was using it normally through SQL, my SQL codes works but it never showed any "tables" tab.

Comment: I'm asking about SQL Developer.  Go to File->New, select Database Connection and create one -- then test it.

Comment: Can you post the image of what you see here?

Comment: Well, thank you guys for help, but I tried and it didn't wok either. So, I simply deleted it and extracted again. Worked fine. Sorry to bother for such a small thing, but I tried to solve this the whole day with no success, tried to search the internet and nothing, I was pretty desperate.

Comment: @Dannyl your thing worked for me ! I wasted almost an hour on this. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the DBA view.  You probably want to be looking at the Connections view.  Go to View and choose "Connections".  That will bring up the window that contains the tree view that lets you navigate to different object types (like tables) rather than the tree view that lets you navigate to different DBA tasks.

Comment: I looked for it too, but, for some reason, it wasn't there. As I said on the comment above, I simply deleted it and extracted again. Worked Fine. Thank you for the attention, anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Your screenshot shows that you have the Data Modeler extension active. All those toolbar buttons are for creating logical data models and ERDs.

It's a little weird as you have a worksheet active, so the worksheet/SQLDev toolbar should be active.

Glad a restart helped.

If this happens again, try Window > Reset Windows to Factory Settings

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `Windows`, try this

```
View(from the top menu bar) --> Connection(click it)
```

Clicking on `Connection` will open the `Connection` view with all the tables.